# Erro na inicialização do Delphi 10

Tags: delphi

Estou com um problema na inicialização do Delphi 10, ele começou a apresentar o erro em anexo após uma atualização do Windows 10. Alguém sabe a solução?

[image: Exception gerada pelo Delphi]

Comment: tente colocar seu projeto no C: e executar. Pelo erro "O nome do arquivo é muito grande" as vezes acontece quando colocamos em varias subpastas

Comment: Mesmo erro, dá a mensagem quando abro qualquer projeto ou executo o bds.exe direto.

Comment: Você modificou algo no código depois de atualizar pro Windows 10?

Comment: Não, na verdade o erro ocorre na inicialização da IDE.

Comment: Qual versão do Windows? qual o caminho do executavel?

Comment: Utilizo o Windows 10 e o executável se encontra em C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\bin, que não é um diretório muito longo...